# Facebook sending permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Just trying to understand how are permissions work. I send a message from page(I'm the admin) via API to myself:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/_page_id_/
{
  "recipient": {
    "id": "_my_id_"
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
  }
}
```

receive:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#230) Requires pages_messaging permission to manage the object",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 230,
    "fbtrace_id": "CofCWlt4GXP"
  }
}
```

Why does facebook reject me?

UPD1.

I do not understand the reason because of:

> When your app is in Development Mode, the Send API will only work for
>   admins, developers and testers of the app. After your app is approved
>   and public, it will work for the general public.

Do I still need special permissions in development mode?

UPD2.

[image]

I got permission, but still not allowed to send messages via API:

```
{
  "error": {
   "message": "(#230) Requires pages_messaging permission to manage the object",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 230,
    "fbtrace_id": "GJRxafu1uNx"
  }
}
```

Comment: Right below what you just quoted, it clearly says: _“The Send API requires the `pages_messaging` permission.”_

Answer (score 2):

you need permissions for that. `pages_messaging` permission for that.

Check this page for more on how it works. [Pages_messaging permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-pages_messaging)

> This allows you to send and receive messages through a Facebook Page, but only within 24h hours after a user action. For post 24h messages see the next permission. Conversations through this API can only begin when someone indicates—through a Messenger plugin or directly messaging you—that they want to receive messages from you.
> Try getting a token with that permission from the graph explorer.

It should work after then.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

UPDATE:

Yes, you need specific permissions to be able to execute some of these actions. They're referring to the availability of the app there for use.
When the app is in dev mode even the admin needs to get a token with the needed permissions to perform certain actions.

Comment: I received a message(from myself) via Webhooks and _immediately_ tried to response/send a message back.

Comment: I don't get you. You sent a message to the page? And now trying to reply?

Comment: 1) Admin of the page send a message to the page 2) Page received a message via(registered earlier) Webhook 3) Process the message 4) Send back an answer to admin via Send API 5) Message is rejected by facebook. Make sense?

Comment: And the API tells you, that you respond to such a message, you need a certain permission first. Which the documentation also explicitly mentions. Now what about that is unclear ...?

Comment: @danilabagroff that is the error is explicitly stated in the response message. You don't have the required permission and I have given you a link on how to go about getting it.

Comment: @CBroe does not help